# Why does pipe inside if() function fail when first argument is referred with a '.'

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, magrittr

I spent 45 mins to get a very simple `if()` inside a loop to work, but I want to understand why it was failing in the first place.

It's a simple R Magrittr pipe chain with a `if()` condition in braces `{}`

Here's the simplified reprex (reproducible example)

```r
library(tidyverse) # load tidyverse library

a <- tibble(a1 = 1:6, a2 = 6:1, a3 = rep(c('a', 'b'),3), a4 = as_factor(5:10))

# function to check the data type of a column

# Fails
check1 <- function(.df, .colm)
{
  .df %>%
     { if(. %>% pull(var = {{.colm}}) %>% is.character()) 1 else 2} # pull .colm from .df and check if is char

}

# Works
check2 <- function(.df, .colm)
{
  .df %>%
    {if(pull(., var = {{.colm}}) %>% is.character()) 1 else 2} # pull .colm from .df and check if is char
  
}

check1(a, a1) # Fails
#> Error in if (. %>% pull(var = {: argument is not interpretable as logical
check2(a, a1) # Works
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also do let me know if there's a simpler way to check the `class()` of a column in a data frame that can be generalized to have the column name taken from user input to a funtion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. both the calls to check1 and check2 give errors because their inputs have not been defined
2. a magrittr pipeline that begins with just a dot on the left hand side defines a function so in the first case the part within the condition portion of the `if` is defining a function, not a logical condition.

   ```
    library(magrittr)

    f <- . %>% { . ^ 2 }
    f(3)
    ## [1] 9
   ```

This fails for the same reason

```
      library(purrr)
      library(dplyr)

      BOD %>% { if (. %>% pull("demand") %>% is.numeric) 1 else 0 }
```

but this works since the left hand side is now (.) instead of just .

```
      BOD %>% { if ( (.) %>% pull("demand") %>% is.numeric) 1 else 0 }
```

Comment: Oops. I edited my reprex with the data `a` included.

For some reason, I had the misconception that the part of the pipeline within the braces `{}` defines a function (unary operator) without evaluating it, but you are right that starting with the '.' causes this behavior - Source : [Magrittr intro](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/articles/magrittr.html) point 6

Comment: So is it correct to say that enclosing the dot like this `(.)` is forcing the function to be evaluated thereby returning the value instead of a function? I guess I was expecting it to be evaluated since the whole internal pipe was already enclosed in braces :`if(--internal pipe--)`

Comment: No. If (.) is used then it is no longer defining a function.